# camel component 'velocity' not found

Tags: apache-camel, velocity, apache-servicemix

I implement *.vm template in my routing application (Servicemix)
but after deploying JAR archive I get this error

karaf@root> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-38" org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: 
Failed to create route route14 at: >>> To[velocity:getPayments.vm] <<< in route: Route(route14)[[From[direct:start]] -> [To[velocity:getPayme... 
because of Failed to resolve endpoint: velocity://getPayments.vm due to: 
No component found with scheme: velocity

I followed this manual
*http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident-part4.html*

and pointed camel-velocity in pom.xml with same camel-core version

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
 <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-velocity</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Does anybody know, what the matter is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing changed even after ServiceMix restarting, but **I found solution**.
after init-ing of CamelContext I add camel components manually.

```
import org.apache.camel.component.velocity.*;
import org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.*;

....

private CamelContext camel;

.....

camel = new DefaultCamelContext();
camel.addComponent("velocity", new VelocityComponent());
camel.addComponent("spring-ws",new SpringWebserviceComponent());
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Karaf you need to add the velocity feature:

```
feature:install camel-velocity
```

Or if using Karaf 4.x

```
feature:install camel-velocity
```

Comment: so, I installed it and got it in bundle list
[ 251] [Active] [ ] [ ] [ 50] camel-velocity (2.12.3)
also, I changed version in pom and after deploying application starts,
but when I send request, I get same error 
" No component found with scheme: velocity"

I tried to start camel-velocity bundle, it remains stay "Active"

Comment: Try restarting the bundle that contains your route

Comment: you've got a mistake in command, should be `feature:install ...`